# Type mismatch in redecleration of remove and too few parameters in call to remove

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void remove();
void edit();

//I need not send return value from function
int main()
{
   //I need not send any parameters to function
   remove();
}

void remove()
{
    int flag;
    printf("enter flag");
    scanf("%d",&flag);
    if (flag==1)
        edit();
}
```

Error message:

> Type mismatch in redecleration of remove and too few          parameters in call to remove

Comment: I have returned value in main and do have edit function body

Comment: You must not redefine functions of the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

The function [`remove`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/remove) is already defined in [`stdio.h`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/stdio_h.htm). Therefore, you can't name your own function `remove`. You should name it something else, like `my_remove`.

Also, when you don't want to pass any parameters to a function, put `void` in the parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_remove(void); 
void edit(void);

//I need not send return value from function
int main(void)
{
    //I need not send any parameters to function
    my_remove();
    return 0;
}

void my_remove(void)
{
    int flag;
    printf("enter flag");
    scanf("%d", &flag);
    if (flag == 1)
        edit();
}

void edit(void)
{
    printf("edit\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the function `remove()` is already defined in `stdio.h`, which your code includes. So to fix your code, just rename your `remove` function to a different name, like `remove_flag()`.